# Google Sign-In API Hang with uncaught error Failed to get parent origin from URL hash

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-signin, google-oauth

I'm using Google Sign-In JavaScript client for months without problem.
But recently when user tapping on sign in button from webapp that added to homescreen, the signin pop-up just hang without showing any content.

When debugged via remote debugging, an error is displayed in console pane:

```
Uncaught Failed to get parent origin from URL hash!
```

originated from 4188232449-v2-idpiframe.js:136 (javascript loaded internally by google library).

I'm sure it's not programming/config error since the same webapp was previously working for months without problem, and I haven't modified any code.

I've tried google search for this particular problem and browse Google documentation for any recent changes in Google Sign-In API without any luck.

Is it bug from Google API Javascript client library, glitch from recent Chrome browser update on Android, or there is some changes in API usage that I doesn't yet aware?

Library used is https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js

This is init param for gapi.auth2.init():

```
{
  client_id: GAPI_CID,  // defined as constant
  cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
  prompt: 'select_account',
  ux_mode: 'popup',
  fetch_basic_profile: true
}
```

Any insight will be much appreciated. Thank you.

P.S.: This problem is different with [Uncaught Failed to get parent origin from URL hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52726303/uncaught-failed-to-get-parent-origin-from-url-hash) since on that case the **problem is caused by misconfiguration of required credential** in Google API console.
If you never had succedded in integrating sign-in flow with your app, perhaps answer from that post can help you.

Otherwise, if you **have had successfully** integrated sign-in flow for some time but **recently problem suddenly/erratically appears** with symptom of blank screen on popped-up window, than you have same problem with me.

Comment: I've had an app (Electron) using the same set up for a year now and this just started happening today. Google must have changed something.

Comment: did you find a workaround?

Comment: We are seeing the same error. We have a thin Electron wrapper around our website. The error happens in the Electron app but not on the vanilla site. In the Electron app, `process.versions` contains "electron": "2.0.9" and "chrome": "61.0.3163.100"

Comment: Updating Electron to the latest stable 3.0.3 with Chrome 66, or to 4.0.0-nightly with Chrome68 did not help.

Comment: Possibly related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52723971/google-sign-in-javascript-client-not-working-on-pwa-app

Comment: Also just started running into this same issue a day or so ago with Google Sign-In in my Electron app, which is similarly a light-weight wrapper around a website. The web version is working fine, but the error is occurring on the Electron side. Does feel like a change on Google's side. Did you find any solution @JasonMorrison or @howMuchCheeseIsTooMuchCheese?

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue with an Electron app.  Worked fine for years, something must have changed.

Comment: I found a bug report here, but it doesn't seem to be getting any attention. So would encourage you to share your issue as well there: https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/473

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught Failed to get parent origin from URL hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52726303/uncaught-failed-to-get-parent-origin-from-url-hash)

Answer (score 7):

I can confirm we are experiencing the same problems at my company since recently. It seems a bit erratic, not 100% of the time. But for some users, some time, they are met with an empty sign-in popup with the url pointing to "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/iframe" but nothing happens.

Comment: same here too. it's a random issue

Comment: @sniii have you tried using `ux_mode: 'redirect',`, see my answer below

Comment: Sorry for downvoting, but this is not an answer, just a confirmation of the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Not a complete answer yet, but this may be a reasonable workaround for some. I updated the `ux_mode` to use `redirect` and it is partially working now.

```
auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
    client_id: '1234.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    scope: 'profile email',
    ux_mode: 'redirect',
    redirect_uri: 'https://blahblah.io/oauth2callback'
})
```

NOTE: it seems `redirect_uri` is required, contrary to Google's docs. This isn't a perfect drop-in replacement, but it solves the "URL hash!" error

This [blog post](http://mcaikovski.blogspot.com/2018/01/google-sign-in-into-website-using.html) and the Git Repo in it could also be helpful for anyone attempting to use `redirect`

Comment: hey this worked for me in the sense I get the dialog back, but the flow scheme is different: instead of opening a popup replaces the main page with google's auth that at the end redirects to the callback url. Not ideal for my electron structure, but I have managed to support this flow as well. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

My electron app started to fail today for the same reason. Been debugging quite a lot and I think found the reason, but don't know how to solve it, why it happened, or if it is electron or google's fault.

In my electron app, I have 2 `webviews`, one for the main content and another one for google popup dialogs.

So when google needs to open the authentication, it generates this IFRAME:

```
    <iframe id="ssIFrame_google" 
                sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin" aria-hidden="true" 
                src="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/iframe#origin=https%3A%2F%2Fxxxx.com&amp;rpcToken=dxxd318480305.4777704" 
                style="... display: none;"></iframe>
```

**Mind that the URL has HASH parameters: your origin and the token.**

However, when on the electron side I capture the new-window event in order to open the URL myself in another webview, the event I receive LACKS the hash parameters:

```
event { 
  type : "new-window",
  url:"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/iframe",
  .
  .
}
```

So what google's iframe is complaining about (I debugged it) is exactly that it can't find the `origin` and `rpctoken` parameters **that should be in the hash parameters**.

For a reason I don't understand (I haven't updated electron) the `new-window` event does not receive the full url anymore.

Using @howMuchCheeseIsTooMuchCheese answer below I have changed the flow to use the redirect callback, then capture that callback myself and restart the application. It is not ideal, but at least I can login into my applications.