# Google Sign-In JavaScript client not working on PWA App

Tags: oauth, google-api, progressive-web-apps

Since yesterday when I use the gapi.auth2 to do a Google Sign-in on an installed PWA app on Android, the App opens the browser window to select the user, but it remains blank.
The same page on the Chrome browser on Android open the user selection as usual. The code is the same, from the same server. The code was not modified in more than 15 days. I presume the problem is some change in the gapi JS client code from Google servers.
Inspecting the PWA Google Sign-in tab on chrome shows the following error:

**Uncaught Failed to get parent origin from URL hash!**

The origins on Google Developer Console are ok.

Anyone has any clue how to solve this?

Edit1: Code chunk

```
initGoogle() {
    this.ngRedux.dispatch({ type: SN_INIT_GOOGLE });
    Observable.create((observer: Observer<any>) => {

        let head = document.getElementsByTagName('head');
        (<any>window).__ongload = () => {
            gapi.load('auth2', () => {
                gapi.auth2.init({
                    client_id: `${AppConfig.google.clientID}`
                }).then(() => {
                    this.auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
                    this.googleInitiated();
                    observer.complete();
                }, (err) => {
                    this.log.error(err);
                    observer.error(err);
                });
            });
        };
        let script: HTMLScriptElement = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=__ongload';
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        head[ 0 ].appendChild(script);
    }).pipe(
        timeout(AppConfig.google.timeout),
        retry(AppConfig.google.retries),
        catchError(error => {
            this.googleInitError();
            return observableEmpty();
        }),
        take(1)
    ).subscribe();
}

async googleLogin(scope: string = 'profile email', rerequest: boolean = false, type: string = SN_GOOGLE_LOGIN): Promise<GoogleUser> {
    let goopts = {
        scope: this.ngRedux.getState().socialNetworks.getIn([ 'google', 'grantedScopes' ]),
        prompt: rerequest ? 'consent' : undefined
    };
    try {
        const user: GoogleUser = await this.auth2.signIn(<any>goopts);
        ...
        return user;
    } catch (error) {
        ...
        return error;
    }
}
```

Edit 2: Error screenshot

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1k3w.png)

Comment: Could you please provide code's chunk so we know what you did (and maybe did wrong) ? Also error's log's sceenshot may be useful sometime

Comment: Possible related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52713993/google-sign-in-api-hang-with-uncaught-error-failed-to-get-parent-origin-from-url

Comment: Code chunk and error screenshot added

Comment: @MarcosB any solution found till yet ?

Comment: @Ahmad Is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52726303/uncaught-failed-to-get-parent-origin-from-url-hash/52726399#52726399). I had not registered my domain under Credential -> My OAuth Client ID -> Authorized JavaScript origins. By adding, it started working. Check the similar case for your app. It may help.

Comment: It is already added. When is not added I get a permission denied, not a blank screen.

Comment: @MarcosB did you find out any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

This bug should be fixed. Cannot reproduce it any more.

Comment: For me it is still happening.

Comment: I just noticed that on chrome I am getting the same problem but on Safari and Firefox it works well for me. to make it even worse when I switch to chrome incognito mode it works! wth?