# Google login is stuck at oauth2/iframe

Tags: oauth-2.0, angular6, google-oauth, google-signin, google-oauth-java-client

I have an Angular 6 + PWA app which consist of google login.

I have integrated google login using [angular-6-social-login](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-6-social-login).

The app was  working absolutely fine until the google pop stopped appearing.

When i investigated, found out that google pop up url formed was :

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/iframe

Previously it used to be :

https://accounts.google.com/signin/oauth/oauthchooseaccount?client_id=......

basically it was a huge url.

I haven't changed anything in the code and this error occurred out of nowhere.

The google pop up appears in localhost:4200, but when used this app on mobile as PWA, it gets stuck on the oauth2/iframe url.

Can anyone please tell me what the issue could be?

Comment: I believe this might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52713993/google-sign-in-api-hang-with-uncaught-error-failed-to-get-parent-origin-from-url

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been solved by google as of this morning. Hence no change was initiated at  my end.